# Bijectivity of the Inverse of a Bijection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $f:A\to B$ is a bijective mapping, is $f^{-1} : B\to A$ also bijective?

Can you also give a detailed proof?

Comment: Will you give us your definition of a bijection? And what you've thought about/

Comment: @mixedmath bijective means one-to-one and onto function.

Comment: One of us giving a detailed proof isn't really helpful to your understanding. If you have thought about how to begin such a proof and are stuck in a particular place, then showing you how to get unstuck is a great use of our time, since it will be a great learning opportunity for you. But reading someone else's proof is not.